# Discord.js "expected token to be present"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am following the toutorial for discord.js and every time i run "node deploy-commands.js" it gives me this error:

```
PS D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0> node deploy-commands.js
cmd1 active
cmd2 active
Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present
    at _RequestManager.resolveRequest (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:876:15)
    at _RequestManager.queueRequest (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:849:46)
    at REST.raw (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1003:32)
    at REST.request (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:999:33)
    at REST.put (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:993:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0\deploy-commands.js:19:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
PS D:\github\TAD\Alienbot-2.0>
```

I have followed all the instructions and check the other post similar to this. (It didnt work :( )

The code is:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

any help would be much appreaceated! :D

Comment: Have you checked the value of `token`?

Comment: yup, its all working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "*I am following the toutorial for discord.js*" I assume you are referring to [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20220908155331/https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html).

Your issue is probably in your `config.json` file, **which you should have in the same directory (i.e. folder) as your `deploy-commands.js` file.**

[image: An example of the directory]

Your `config.json` file should look like this inside:

```
{
    "clientId": "your-client-id-goes-here",
    "guildId": "your-server-id-goes-here",
    "token": "your-token-goes-here"
}
```

In the quotes that say `your-token-goes-here` you should instead have your Bot Token. [You can find out how to get the Bot Token for your bought here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20220913224708/https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-token/)